# Configuration in a S3 bucket: bad idea?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm quite new in AWS. I have designed an architecture that uses Api Gateway to call a lambda function written in java. Since I have some configuration I decided to create an S3 file to store a standard Java configuration file there and load it when needed. This took a lot of time, about 15 sec, for a very small file.
To read the file I'm using `AmazonS3Client` client class, Do I have other options?

```
 long ms = System.nanoTime();
        AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain());
        GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest("bucket","filepath");
        InputStream inputStream = client.getObject(request).getObjectContent();
        try {
            PropertiesConfiguration p = new PropertiesConfiguration();
            p.load(inputStream);
            composite.addConfiguration(p);
            log.debug(String.format("Configuration read in %f mS",(System.nanoTime()-ms)/1000000f));

        }catch (ConfigurationException e) {
            logger.error("error reading configuration on S3:"+e);

        }
```

So the questions: if storing the config file in an s3 bucket is a bad idea, where is supposed to be stored a configuration?
Is that performance normal? I'm thinking in using s3 a lot in my architecture for something else, but having a 15 sec handshake for a file is, of course, unacceptable.

Comment: 15s seems like quite a lot!! Even if you consider the increased latency on the first time a Lambda function is called, it is still orders of magnitude slower than it should be. What's the size of that configuration file?

Comment: S3, dynamodb (which claims to have single digit millisecond response times) or anything that can store data on the internet. Though ideally you avoid external configuration since it needs to be read every time.

Comment: @BrunoReis very small as you guess, is 3 lines. Time seems to be spent in cretaing the rest call.

Comment: @BrunoReis maybe is because is the first ( and actually the only ) call I make to s3?

Comment: @FelicePollano - it's really hard to tell without looking specifically at your code and environment... Anyways, a single call to S3 (even if it is the "first") shouldn't take that long (not even 10% or 5% of that...). Have you tracked those 15s down to the `s3Client.getObject(...)` API call in isolation? How did you measure it?

Comment: @BrunoReis I added the code in the post

Comment: You're measuring the entire download, not just connection establishment. As such it could be that it's blocking in `p.load` or `composite.addConfiguration`. And just to be sure, it prints values as high as `Configuration read in 15000.000000 mS`? Confusion when converting milli / nano seconds & locale formatting happens far too often. You could btw try if adding a buffered stream in between helps. Just in case neither aws nor the properties loader adds one.

Comment: @zapl yes it is 15000.something. You ar erightr I'm measuring the Properties class, but I can bet it does not take almost time

Answer (score -1):

In this case I think you should try to store it with [EBS](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/). But it will cost you more because EBS is optimized I/O and EBS storage is organized into volumes and once an EBS volume is attached to a server it is treated like a local disk drive.

Comment: Lambda does not work with EBS because Lambda functions are executed "somewhere in the cloud" (i.e. amazon's lambda worker cluster), EBS works only on known EC2 instances, which you explicitly don't have in case of lambda.

Comment: Thank you, my fault, I forgot he use Lambda in this case, sorry.

Comment: @zapl So i think in this case perharp it will better if we use a key value database for store configuration, isnt it?

Comment: Either that, or you bake the configuration into the functions. You can even automate that and have multiple functions with different configurations. E.g. with a utility lambda function that has a function template and that reacts to changes in dynamodb, it can then bake & activate new functions dynamically.